# Is it possible to handle the event that causes a WinRT flyout to close?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, flyout

I've got a Windows Store app with a canvas that the user can draw on using the [InkManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/windows.ui.input.inking.inkmanager). In the bottom app bar there are some buttons for choosing color, stroke thickness, etc. These are implemented by showing a flyout element containing for example a color picker:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar IsSticky="True">
        <AppBarButton ...>
            <AppBarButton.Flyout>
                <Flyout>
                    <ColorPicker .../>
                </Flyout>
            </AppBarButton.Flyout>
        </AppBarButton>
    </CommandBar>
</Page>
```

The problem is that most users (including myself) keep tripping over a little issue:
If you tap the button, the flyout opens, and you can select a color. Then you want to start drawing and move your finger (or the stylus) over the canvas, expecting to create a stroke with the new color. However, the touch event only closes the flyout. It seems that the flyout element somehow captures the pointer events (although it is no UIElement).

Is there any way to prevent this issue? Ideally, when you touch the canvas, the flyout would be closed but the same touch event would be handled by the canvas, so you can start drawing immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I think a `Flyout` probably uses a `Popup` control to display its content, so if you could find that - you could change the `IsLightDismissEnabled` property. Otherwise - I'd simply use a `Popup` instead of a `Flyout` so you could control its parameters.

Comment: If I use a popup and set IsLightDismissEnabled to true, it shows exactly the same behavior. But that at least explains how the "pointer capture" of the flyout works.

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this:

```
var flyout = new SettingsFlyout();
Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.Pointer pointer = null;
flyout.PointerMoved += (s, e) => pointer = e.Pointer;
flyout.Unloaded += (s, e) => flyout.ReleasePointerCapture(pointer);

// cause it to hide
flyout.Hide();
```

Best of luck!

Comment: I wonder if pointer capture is really your issue. But without more information, this is what I can give you. :)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using a Flyout (not SettingsFlyout), which doesn't have any of these events or a ReleasePointerCapture method.